# Removed Thirtdparty webvitals issue

Tags: web, core-web-vitals

I checked the pageinsights of "http://www.briddles.com/riddle/9-bodmas?l=333"

[image]

Most of these are thirdparty. How can i sove it ?

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 important groups there:

1. Youtube
2. Google Ads or analytics
3. Facebook

Here is what I would do:

- 1. I see the youtube player is hidden by default, I would reserve some space for the player (maybe with a lightweight placeholder) and only append the iframe when the user clicks "view answer". [This `lite-youtube` web component](https://github.com/justinribeiro/lite-youtube) is awesome and might help you out. Trust me.
- 2. Normally Google ads is not something you want to get rid of. I would just make sure to load these scripts with the `async` attribute at least.
- 3. For the facebook comments I imagine 3 approaches:

  - 3.1. Render a placeholder with a button saying "See comments" or something like that and only fetch the scripts when the user press that button.
  - 3.2. Use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) so when comments section scroll into view, fetch de scripts and render. (You will have to reserve some space to avoid CLS).
  - 3.3. Remove the comments section (if there is almost no usage) or use a different provider that is optimized for web vitals. I don't know which one, but it's still an option.

---

Extra recommendations:

- The main image is too heavy for mobile users, try to use a responsive image, compress the image and choose a lighter format like `webp` for browsers that support it. [More info about image optimization here](https://web.dev/fast/#optimize-your-images).
- Reduce the amount of fonts you use and, if possible, host it by yourself and use a CDN. Google fonts is practical but to host your fonts is better for performance.